# CircularProgressIndicator is not showing in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  loadData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    final catalogJson =
        await rootBundle.loadString("assets/files/catalog.json");
    final decodedData = jsonDecode(catalogJson);
    var productsData = decodedData["products"];
    CatalogModel.items = List.from(productsData)
        .map<Item>((item) => Item.fromMap(item))
        .toList();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Catalog App"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: (CatalogModel.items != null && CatalogModel.items.isNotEmpty)
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: CatalogModel.items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemWidget(
                  item: CatalogModel.items[index],
                ),
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
    );
  }
```

Im trying to display the CircularProgressIndicator in my flutter app before data is loaded, but it is not rendering...   I have also tried to set background color and color..but it doesnt work..

Comment: FutureBuilder<Widget>(
        future: //async or loading function//,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          
          //whatever you want to show after done loading in this case i put (Widget)//
          
        })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you can solve the problem like this:

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: _loadData(),
      //future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
         return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        else
          return Main();    /
      }
    );
```

`_loadData` should return a `Future<List>`.

***Example***

```
Future<List> _loadData() {
    return Future.wait([
      //load Data Implement
    ]);
```

Comment: where should I put this code...?

Comment: Just put it inside build(). Then, when you run the app, CircularProgressIndicator() is executed while data is being loaded, and if all data is loaded, you can call your UI to Main().

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the handy tools that flutter provides: The [Future Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

This handles loading async data, displaying it once loaded, and even showing a loading widget while it's not (yet).